# How to Trigger Google Apps Script when i get new email

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, gmail

I have created a Google apps Script that check email subject and if match get message body and send to another email address. It is working fine when i use manually, but i wan to add trigger that auto run if new message with same subject has arrive.

this is my code

```
function getInbox(){
  const q = GmailApp.search('subject:SendEmailInboundReport', 0,1 );
  var qmsg = q[0].getMessages();
  var msg = qmsg[0].getPlainBody(); 
  var attachments = qmsg[0].getAttachments();

  title = qmsg[0].getPlainBody().match(/w\d{4}.+?c\d{4}/);
  var tite1 = (title && title[0]) ? title[0] : 'No title';
  tmp = msg.replace(tite1, '').replace(/\s/g, '');

  GmailApp.sendEmail('',tite1,'',{
      attachments: [attachments[0]],
      bcc: tmp
    })
}
```

Comment: All you can do is poll

Comment: In your situation, is this official document useful? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push